# How to send arguments to an already running program in c#?

Tags: c#, c++

so i'm trying to send arguments (using c#) to an already running program (native).

The native program goes like this:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   Client *client = GetClient(hWnd, FALSE);
   
   switch(msg)
   {
      case WM_CREATE:
      {
         HMENU hSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(hWnd, false);
         AppendMenu(hSysMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
         
         AppendMenu(hSysMenu, MF_STRING, SysMenuIds::Run,       TEXT("&Run..."));
         break;
      }
      case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
      {
         if(wParam == SC_RESTORE)
            SetEvent(client->minEvent);

         else if(wParam == SysMenuIds::Run)
         {
            EnterCriticalSection(&g_critSec);
            if(!SendInput(client->connections[Connection::input], SysMenuIds::Run, NULL, NULL))
               PostQuitMessage(0);
            LeaveCriticalSection(&g_critSec);
            break;
         }
         
         return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what i'm trying is to execute `SysMenuIds::Run` using c#.

i could find the window using `FindWindow` but i couldn't find how to execute the menu command (`SysMenuIds::Run`) using c#

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr windowPtr = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Window1");
    if (windowPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Window not found");
        return;
    }

    var wParam = "SysMenuIds::startRun";

    SendMessage(windowPtr, 0x0112, wParam, IntPtr.Zero);

    Console.Read();
}
```

I can close the window but i just don't know how to send the custom "`SysMenuIds::startRun`" command

Comment: Take a look at the Win32 API SendMessage function.

Comment: Look at www.pinvoke.net which has lots of examples of what you are trying to do.  See user32 FindWindow and GetWindow.

Comment: i tried but i  just don't know how to send a custom command (look at my last code)

Comment: Obvioulsy, you cannot pass a string `"SysMenuIds::startRun"` and hope that it will match a constant (or enum value) `SysMenuIds::Run`. You have to somehow put those constants in C# code. C++ does not have reflection thus it is not possible to find the value from metadata. You would be able by using C++/CLI and writing managed code in C++ but if you were doing that, then you would provide a function for that purpose anyway. By the way, it seems a bit suspicious to have a critical section around SendInput...